# Why was my "low quality answer" flag declined?

Tags: support, declined-flags, specific-answer

For the answer *[VBA Excel: The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447914/vba-excel-the-specified-dimension-is-not-valid-for-the-current-chart-type/56787616#56787616)*. Why if clearly the answer is of low quality?

Comment: probably a *bad* answer but not realy low quality

Comment: The flag is for "very low quality". The "very" here is a subtle, but crucial distinction in this site.

Comment: It's all very subjective then.

Comment: If moderation was completely objective, humans wouldn't be doing it.

Comment: Can I raise it with whoever declined my flag?

Comment: *This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.* --> I don't really see formatting or content problems. It deserves a downvote probably but not a flag

Comment: When (the timestamp please) did you flag that answer?

Comment: Don't flag good faith attempts to answer a question. If they are wrong, downvote them.

Comment: “Very low quality” means “unsalvageable”, or “needs to be deleted”. It does *not* mean “this answer is wrong” (flags never mean this: moderators do not judge the technical accuracy of answers), and it does not mean “needs to be edited” (you can edit it yourself; moderator intervention is not required).

Comment: @rene Doesn’t matter; there are no edits. Unless you’re thinking he flagged it during the grace period? That’s possible, but also invisible to moderators, so it would never affect flag dispensation. Also, hard to imagine a previous revision of that answer looking much worse...

Comment: @CodyGray it was more due to the three review queues that answer had been in so my reasoning was that the declined flag could be related to the outcome of those reviews. I kind of stopped when that low quality review was terminated (after getting two recommend deletion) assuming a mod probably handled it. I left my comment for curiousity.

Comment: Ah, makes sense, @rene. I sometimes forget flags can be handled by non-mods. This was indeed handled by a mod. Not me, though!  slacker ->

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be an actual attempt to answer the question. It's not an especially good answer, but that's different than being a "Very Low Quality" answer. The correct thing to do in this case is downvote and/or comment explaining how to improve the answer, not to flag it.

Comment: You forgot editing. Granted, it may require some psychic powers, or at least a willingness to make assumptions. This one was pretty obvious to me, once you get past the weak English skills.

Comment: @Cody Your edit helps a lot, the answer is a lot better now. I missed it on account of not knowing VBA. But yeah, I agree - if you know how to edit to fix something, you probably should.